# How to serve pages from another domain using Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

We already have an existing domain running in production (my.domain1) and we wanted to create another domain which will be hosted in a separate server (my.domain2) which will serve pages that are already available from the production domain. If I access "my.domain2/my_account.html", nginx should then get the content of the page from "my.domain1/profile.html". Unfortunately, I'm always getting 404 message. I've ready so many articles on how to use proxy_pass but I think I'm missing something. Please help.

Here is my configuration for domain1:

> server {
>     listen 80;
>     root /var/www/domain1;
>     index index.html index.htm;
>     server_name my.domain1;
>   }

and here is for the domain2:

> server {
>     listen 80;
>     root /var/www/domain2;
>     index index.html index.htm;
>     server_name my.domain2;
>     location /my_account.html {
>       proxy_pass http://my.domain1;
>       proxy_redirect off;
>     }
>   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've already figured it out. I'll just have to basically specify the equivalent url for both domain1 and domain2. Below is my final configuration. Hope it helps someone out there.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/domain1;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name my.domain1;
}
```

and here is for the domain2:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/domain2;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name my.domain2;
    location /my_account.html {
        proxy_pass http://my.domain1/profile.html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   root /var/www/domain1;
   index index.html index.htm;
   server_name my.domain1;
 }

server {
   listen 80;
   root /var/www/domain1;
   index index.html index.htm;
   server_name my.domain2;
 }
```

Basically just make the root directive the same as that for domain 1

Comment: This is not possible as the domains are hosted in separate servers. Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question for it.